# Swift: variable gets value assigned in the wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, variables, variable-assignment

I'm probably missing something basic here but I have two `ViewControllers` called `ListController`(starting VC) and `ExamplesController` and a variable called `selectedCell` that is declared in `ListController` then its value is changed in `ListController` by the `tableView` `didSelectRowAt indexPath` function based on the row the user taps on. When a user taps on a cell, `ExamplesController` will be presented (via segue in IB), but the value of `selectedCell` doesn't change until I go back to `ListController`. So the order in which things execute now is:

> `selectedCell` gets initialised with a value of 0
>
> user taps on a cell (let's say index 3)
>
> `ExamplesController` is presented with title 0
>
> user goes back to `ListController`
>
> `selectedCell` gets assigned the value 3

Here's a simplified version of the code.

```
var selectedCell = 0

class ListController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCell = indexPath.row
        print("Tapped on \(selectedCell)")
    }

}


class ExamplesController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var chapterTitle: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        chapterTitle.text = "\(chapterTitles[selectedCell])"
    }

}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm doing this from IB via a segue: https://ibb.co/9T1djy0

Comment: If the segue to the ExamplesController is setup in IB then that gets fired before the `didSelectRowAt` method of the delegate is called which is what is causing your problem.  It would really be better to either create the segue and then just call it in the 'didSelectRowAt' method or to keep the segue defined in IB and use the `prepare` method on the view controller which is executed before the second view controller is presented.

Comment: I understand, thanks for clarifying. I've tried presenting the VC from inside the didSelectRow function and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook the segue from the vc itself not from the cell and use inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifer:"SegueName",sender:indexPath.row)
```

---

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?)  {  
  if segue.identider == "SegueName"  {
     let des = segue.destination as! ExampleVC
     des.selectedCell = sender as! Int
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Uploader Of Truth's explanation + your solution helped me fix the problem.